# Function not evaluated in CloudDeploy

Tags: dynamic, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I am trying to create a LocatorPane on the Wolfram cloud, but am hitting a snag.  The LocatorPane needs a couple of helper functions.  When run locally, everything works fine.  When I deploy it to the cloud, these helper functions are not evaluated.

Here is a toy example that shows the issue

```
CloudDeploy[
dog[pt_]:=Norm[pt];
DynamicModule[{pt={1,1}/2},
{LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],Dynamic@If[Norm[pt]<1.,Graphics[{Gray,Disk[]}],Graphics[{Red,Disk[]}]]],Dynamic[pt],Dynamic[dog[pt]]}]
,Permissions->"Public"]
```

In addition to displaying a disk, this should also display the coordinates of the locator and evaluate the function *dog*.  Instead, the *dog* function is not evaluated.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: Output of code]

Comment: Let me know if the linked answer does not fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kuba.  I would prefer not Manipulate.  CloudDeploy has an option IncludeDefinitions ->True, which I thought would guarantee the helper functions would be included.

Comment: DynamicModule has the SaveDefinitions option as well. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Thanks, Kuba!  I didn't realize DynamicModule had that option.  I just tried it and it works perfectly.